# Errors thrown on functions that haven't been called

Tags: javascript, html, function, date

I am currently receiving the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

In regards to my issue, all of the information I have found suggests the logical structure and order of my HTML mark-up in conjunction with my JavaScript is closely related to these kinds of errors, often due to DOM load events.

Although this information is useful to know and has aided me in resolving several issues I have faced in the past, it doesn't help me in the slightest with my most recent issue; this error. I have come to this conclusion due to the fact that this error is referring to the start of a function, one of which is not currently being called. How can this error possibly be thrown, when the function hasn't even been executed?

```
<body onload="OnLoad();">
<div id="Wrapper">
<div id="Banner"><h1>Title</h1></div> <!-- End of Banner -->
<div id="Information">
<ul><li><a id="PageViews">Page Visits: 0</a></li>
<li id="Current_Date"><a id="CurrentDate"></a></li></ul>
</div><!-- End of Information -->
<div class="LoginForm"></div><!--End of LoginForm -->
<div id="Footer"></div><!-- End of Footer -->
```

The above HTML mark-up is a very basic summary of the elements I have within the webpage, the following is the function invoked when the body loads:

```
function OnLoad(){
PageViews();
CurrentDate();
if(navigator.cookieEnabled == false){
document.getElementById("RememberMe").style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById("CheckboxText").style.visibility="hidden";
var UserCookie = ReadCookie("Username");
if(UserCookie.length !== 0){
document.getElementById("Username").value = UserCookie;}}}
function PageViews(){
if(CookieCount > 0) { 
document.getElementById("PageViews").innerHTML = "Page Visits: " + CookieCount}}
function CurrentDate(){
var Today = new Date();
var Day = Today.getDate();
var Month = Today.getMonth()+1;
var Year = Today.getFullYear();
if(Day<10){
Day = '0'+Day;}
if(Month<10){
Month ='0'+Month;}
var Today = Day+'/'+Month+'/'+Year;
document.getElementById("CurrentDate").innerHTML = Today;}
```

Here is where things become strange and continue to perplex me, the code presented below is the function in which the error is thrown, yet as aforementioned this function is not called.

```
function Date(){
document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = 'Last Modified: ' +    document.lastModified;}
```

Could someone please explain to me why this occurs and enlighten me as to what it is I am doing wrong and a possible solution?

Comment: `new Date();` basically calls the function `Date`. You should take a look at objects in javascript, they are pretty different than in other languages :)

Comment: `document.getElementById("Date")` ...okay, so where's the element with `id="Date"` that you're looking for with this code? I see one with `id="Current_Date"` and one with `id="CurrentDate"` (bad idea, btw, giving them such similar names), but not one with `id="Date"`.

Comment: There is no element with an ID of *Date*. There is *CurrentDate* and *Current_Date*, perhaps you meant one of those. Likely the function *currentDate* is calling *Date*, and since you have trashed the built–in Date constructor by declaring your own *Date* function… the rest should be obvious.

Comment: Oh man, no line spacing or indenting it is hurting my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Two things pop out at looking at your code.

The [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) in Javascript is just a way of invoking a function that has some specific behaviors around the prototypes of objects.  The implication is that constructors in Javascript are just functions.  So when you named a function `Date` you overrode the [global object `Date` is that is built into Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). This is really bad not just because of the behavior you are seeing but will cause the other Date handling code you have on the page not work. So when you assert your `Date` function is not called, you are wrong. In fact, you are calling it with with the invocation with the `new` operator e.g. `new Date()`

The second and less major is one, but the reason you are seeing an error on that code is that you are looking for an element with the id `Date` which does not appear to exist on your page.